# How to parse the XML file and check each element having children or not in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am having a XML file like below:

```
<customers>
    <customer>
        <name>XXX</name>
        <address>Nagar</address>
        <number>
             <num1>123</num1>
             <num2>456</num2>
        </number>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <name>YYY</name>
        <address>Nagar</address>
        <number>
             <num1>789</num1>
             <num2>012</num2>
        </number>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

I need to parse the entire XML from top to bottom and get the child node information for each element.

Excepted output:(node = children)

```
customers = customer,customer
customer = name,address,number
name = null
address = null
number = num1,num2
num1 = null
num2 = null
customer = name,address,number
name = null
address = null
number = num1,num2
num1 = null
num2 = null
```

I used DOM for this. Below given the code:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
       System.out.println(node.getNodeName()+" = "+node.getChildNodes());
    }
}
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
customers = [customers: null]
customer = [customer: null]
name = [name: null]
address = [address: null]
number = [number: null]
num1 = [num1: null]
num2 = [num2: null]
customer = [customer: null]
name = [name: null]
address = [address: null]
number = [number: null]
num1 = [num1: null]
num2 = [num2: null]
```

Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another loop in your loop, to iterate through children

This works:

```
NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
    {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
        Element element=(Element) node;

        System.out.print(element.getNodeName()+" = ");
        boolean is_first_child=true;

        // CHILDS
        NodeList nodechilds=node.getChildNodes();

        for (int j = 0; j < nodechilds.getLength(); j++)
            {
            Node a_child = nodechilds.item(j);

            if (a_child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                if (!is_first_child) System.out.print (",");
                System.out.print (a_child.getNodeName());

                is_first_child=false;
                }
            }

    if (is_first_child) System.out.print ("null");
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```